# How to have interactivity of Jupyter Notebooks online?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering if there is a site where one can link a Jupyter Notebook and in return be able to run the notebook interactively? Basically an online or cloud version of Jupyter where the input cells can be modified and run live.

I know there is http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/, but that is a static renderer. I want to be able to run the IPythonWidgets that I have used in this [Side Project](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/S-Suren/PythonPlayground/blob/master/Probability_Dice_Analysis.ipynb) that I'm working on. It would be nice to send a link to other people who can interact with it without having a local installation of Jupyter or Anaconda.

I tried to look for duplicates, but I couldn't find anything else that answered my question.

(Also, please ignore the incompleteness in my project. I only uploaded it to show what I meant. I haven't polished it yet. If you go down to In[5], that is where I have coded in some widgets that dynamically change the plot.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is hosting notebooks on Azure: https://notebooks.azure.com/

Unlike Google's Colaboratory, it is already publicly available (status in June 2018).

Azure Notebooks works great with running an Jupyter Notebook online.

Comment: Wow. I read your post only a few minutes ago and I was able to get signed up and get a simple Python 3.6 Notebook running in no time. 

This is very much what I initially was looking for. Binder is also good, but I like how this Azure environment is comprehensive and keeps everything together. Can't wait to get home after work and really dive in to this platform.

Thanks for your feedback to a an old thread!

Comment: Agreed - I was really surprised since I have found Azure to be outpaced by AWS & GCP in everything else. But this just took no time at all. Strongly recommend it for anybody wanting to host Jupyter Notebooks! 

Comment: This excellent article describes the current ways to use Jupyter online https://www.dataschool.io/cloud-services-for-jupyter-notebook/, and explains the pros and cons of each approach.  In particular, it covers, Azur, Colab,CoCalc (https://cocalc.com/doc/jupyter-notebook.html) Kaggle, and more.

Comment: much thanks to @WilliamStein for the excellent link on dataschool   It was an awesome review of options.

Comment: Thanks @leeprevost.  I also **just** added new functionality to https://cocalc.com to completely eliminate the "sign up wall", so people can now use cocalc without making an account.  Morever, for content shared at https://share.cocalc.com, they can just click a big green button and have an interactive running version of that content in seconds.   This fully supports Jupyter notebooks with interactive widgets and associated data files.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to nitind below, I was able to use the correct vocabulary to find my solution. For the people that may stumble across this post with the same mindset I had, I found a site called [Binder](http://mybinder.org/).

As long as you have a GitHub Repo link, the site will turn that into an online interactive notebook for any user with the link. As far as I can tell, this is exactly what I had in mind. I'll come back and edit, if something falls short of my assumptions.

I like to thank nitind again for introducing me to Dashboards as well. I'll definitely dive down into that area and try to combine them with the site I found.

Comment: I am trying Binder's example  notebook: http://mybinder.org/repo/binder-project/example-requirements and it is "loading" for several minutes now...

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into Dashboards? It seems like exactly what you're looking for.

https://github.com/jupyter/dashboards/wiki

Comment: Thanks to you, I went down the rabbit hole and found the answer to my question. Though the dashboards are something that I didn't know about, the solution that I found is exactly what I was looking for in my original question. But I want to thank you for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Google is also now hosting Jupyter notebooks through Colaboratory, a formerly internal only tool that they recently released:

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/unregistered.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use datacabinet to host notebooks on the cloud. https://lab.computer

It is a paid service for homeworks in classrooms.

Disclaimer: I work on Datacabinet.

Answer (score 1):

There are online hosting services for Jupyter notebooks, like [Jupyo.com](https://jupyo.com). With services like Jupyo you can create or open any Python/R/Julia notebook, run cells live, store data, access external network, etc.